# Ionic 2 : how to seperate two tables side by side

Tags: html, css, ionic2

I m trying to align two tables side by side.It is coming but its combining both tables as below.How to seperate two tables

[image]

.scss

when i give margin left completely moving

```
.tablediv {
    margin-top: 2.2vw;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 0vw;
    overflow:auto;
  }
```

.html

```
  <div *ngFor="let Table of Global_TablePerCard[TablePerCardIndexCounter]">
                   <div class="tablediv">
                    <table class="tablesalign">
                      <thead class="tableheader">
                          <div *ngFor = "let Param of Table; let j=index">
                            <div *ngIf = "j == 0; else elsetag">
                                <th class="col"  *ngFor="let value of Param">
                                    {{value}}
                                </th>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                              <ng-template #elsetag>
                                  <tr>
                                    <td *ngFor="let value of Param">
                                      {{value}}
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                              </ng-template>
                            </div>
                      </div>
                    </thead> 
                </table>
              </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: Can you please share the HTML code for tables?

Comment: shared html code @mittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working fine with padding.

```
padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px;
```